# How can I remove contamination from a 1D signal using a U-Net?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, signal-processing

I'm working on a project regarding removing contamination from a 1D signal and I'm running into odd problems.

### The Dataset

I construct the training set myself by taking 1D "pure" signals from one database, and collecting other "contaminant" signals from a different database. I make a contaminated signal by adding on a "contaminant" signal onto the "pure" signal:

`contaminated signal` = `pure signal` + (`fraction` * `contaminant signal`)

The `fraction` is calculated by taking the median of the `pure signal` and multiplying it by a random float between 0.01 and 0.5. By doing this I add on variable amounts of contamination, between 1% and 50% the median level of the `pure signal`.

### The Training Process

The signals (both pure and contaminants) are all positive, so I normalize them by first taking the logarithm of each, then subtracting off their global mean and dividing by their global standard deviation. See histogram below for their distribution before and after.

I use a simple U-Net that takes as input the normalized `contaminated signal` and the target being the normalized `pure signal` with an MSE loss. The last layer of the U-Net is a linear convolution with no activation, and I use LeakyReLU's for the activation of every other layer.

[image: histogram before vs after]

### Results and the Problem

Here is an example of the results I'm getting so far:

[image: First results]

The inferred signal is fairly consistently between the `pure signal` and `contaminated signal`, and quite often one side of the signal is corrected more than the other.

A big problem I'm finding right now is that I can't even over-fit to the data, no matter what hyperparameters (depth, # of filters) I use for the U-Net. I checked to see if the network could accomplish the easier task of simply reconstructing the input, and it had no problems whatsoever with that.

I've also tried to see if the network would be able to train better if given a limited training sample (e.g. only those signals with ~40% contamination levels), but I get similar results.

Is the U-Net just not capable of handling a problem like this? Should I attempt to use something like the [Wave U-Net](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.03185.pdf) instead, where the output is both the `pure signal` and the `contaminant signal`?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @D.W. I edited my post to include the information you mentioned. I'm happy to include anything else you think might help me get an answer!

Comment: I wonder if taking the log may have made the problem harder for the U-Net.  It transforms something linear (pure + contamination) to something non-linear.  I have no proof or evidence for that, just wondering if this might be connected.

Comment: @D.W. I've tried without the log as well (just normalizing with the mean and standard deviation of the original signals). Same results, although maybe slightly better with the log.